# Getting data but not able to display correctly

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am fetching some data and displaying in my screen.

```
 func getAllCatogory(){
        ViewUtils.addActivityView(view: self.view)
        TransportManager.sharedInstance.AllCatogory { (dt, err) in
            ViewUtils.removeActivityView(view: self.view)
            if let _ = err{

            }else{
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    guard let str = dt as? String else { return }
                    let res  = try decoder.decode([AllCatagories].self, from:str.data(using: .utf8)!)
                    self.allCategory = res
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    print(res.count)  // getting count 2
                    print(self.allCategory.count as Any) getting count 2
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

But in my collection view when i am going to append or print its not coming.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionCell


        let ct = self.allCategory[indexPath.item]
           print(ct.menuName as Any)  // getting null
            //cell.productName.text = ct.menuName


        return cell
    }
```

Not sure what might be an issue.Any help on this ??

Thanks in advance !

Update :

```
class AllCatagories: Codable{


    let image : String?
    let isActive : Int?
    let items : [Item]?
    let menuCode : String?
    let menuName : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case image
        case isActive = "is_active"
        case items
        case menuCode = "menu_code"
        case menuName = "menu_name"
    }
}

struct Item : Codable {

    let menuCode : String?
    let name : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case menuCode = "menu_code"
        case name
    }
}
```

here is my model class which i am using for.Main thread to reload the collection view means where exactly ?

Update :

```
 [
  {
    "menu_code" : "NDS",
    "items" : [
      {
        "unit" : "Nos",
        "name" : "Chapathi\/Pulkas",
        "quantity" : 2
      },
      {
        "unit" : "Cup",
        "name" : "Palya\/Curry",
        "quantity" : 1
      }
    ],
    "is_active" : 1,
    "image" : "nds.jpg",
    "menu_name" : "Normal Diet South"
  },
  {
    "menu_code" : "NCCD",
    "items" : [
      {
        "menu_code" : "NDS",
        "name" : "Monday"
      },
      {
        "menu_code" : "NDN",
        "name" : "Tuesday"
      }
    ],
    "is_active" : 1,
    "image" : "NCCD.jpg",
    "menu_name" : "Normal Combo Corporate Diet"
  }
]
```

my json response is here

Comment: show your json and `AllCatagories` model, and make sure you're reloading your collectionview in main thread

Comment: @Pratik Prajapati  i have updated. In main thread measn on viewdidload or view will appear ?

Comment: Why you are converting to Any ?  it is already string so just do `yourLabel.text = self.allCategory[indexPath.item]. menuName`

Comment: write this `self.collectionView.reloadData()` line `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`

Comment: tried with this `print(self.allCategory[indexPath.item].menuName!)
        cell.productName.text = self.allCategory[indexPath.item].menuName` still getting nill

Comment: main.async in viewdidload or  `getAllCatogory`  ??

Comment: @david did you find solution because i have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `convertFromSnakeCase` you have to delete the coding keys, that's the purpose of `convertFromSnakeCase`

And declare the members / properties as much as possible non-optional, not the contrary. In this particular case you would get a Decoding error.

```
struct AllCatagories: Codable {

    let image : String
    let isActive : Int
    let items : [Item]
    let menuCode : String
    let menuName : String
}

struct Item : Codable {
    let unit : String?
    let name : String
    let quantity : Int?
    let menuCode : String?
}
```

And reload the collection view on the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}` in my getAllCatogory ??

Comment: @david yes in `getAllCatogory`

Comment: Yes, there is only one occurrence of `reloadData` in the question

Comment: `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "is_active", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"is_active\", intValue: nil) (\"is_active\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Please read the JSON. If `isActive` is not in every dictionary, revert it to be optional `let isActive : Int?`

Comment: @vadian  i have updated my json in my post.please check

Comment: i revet my model class to old..now i am not getting that error..But menu name is not showing in my colllection view

Comment: The problem is that the types in `items` are quite different. I updated the answer with a possible solution

Comment: @vadian  i tried like this ` for data in res {
                        if let name = data.menuName {
                            print(name)
                        }
                    }` not even its going inside name . i wrote this in my `getallcat` method

Comment: Please use my suggested structs (I would even declare `AllCatagories` as struct) where `menuName` is non-optional. I tested the given JSON successfully with those structs.

Comment: @vadian  again `valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "image", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))`  like that its coming for all image, name code isactive and all

Comment: Sorry, it's very hard to help if the data in the question is not the **real** data. The JSON in the question contains only 2 items (as stated *getting count 2*) and both `image` keys **do** have values, the ***real*** JSON is obviously larger (index 2 indicates that there are at least 3 items) or even different. I tested `for data in res { let name = data.menuName; print(name) }`